# How to get supply levels of a printer via command line (macOS)

Tags: command-line, macos, printing, cups

I'm trying to get the supply levels of a printer via the command line. So far I was able to get some information with a `lpoptions` (`marker-message` property) command. The problem is that the status of it doesn't update automatically. No matter how many pages I print the result of this command doesn't change.

At the same time, the standard UI (cmd+p) print utility of the macOS can get the proper information from the printer. I did a quick investigation and found out that it calls CUPS `ReportLevels` command.

So my question is: is there a way to call that `ReportLevels` command manually if so, how it can be done? Or maybe there is another way to force that refresh?

I would really appreciate any help, thanks in advance!

Comment: There is a site for Mac questions. https://apple.stackexchange.com/